# ¿como puedo hacer que el evento click se ejecute en el interior de un boton?

Tags: javascript

Quiero que el evento click de un botón se ejecute al presionar en cualquier parte del botón y no lo consigo.

```
 d.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{      
  if(e.target.matches(".editar")){
    $formulario.nombre.value=e.target.dataset.nombre;       
    $formulario.constelacion.value=e.target.dataset.constelacion;       
    $formulario.id.value=e.target.dataset.id;   
  }
 });**
```

Answer (score 0):

Si muestras la parte de código en donde se encuentra declarado el boton va a ser mas fácil detectar si hay un problema. También cuando estás tratando de lograr algo (como el click de un boton) y no puedes te recomiendo empezar con algo mas simple, es decir evita la lógica interna del botón (`if(e.target.matches(".editar"))`) puede que no te esté funcionando porque no se cumple con la condición.

Te dejo de todos modos una implementación de un botón con el metodo `addEventListener`. En el mismo podrás notar que no hay ninguna propiedad que indique que el listener se ejecutará en cualquier parte del boton.

```js
var c = 0;
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Click click click: " + c;
  c++;
});
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Dale click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><strong>Nota:</strong> addEventListener() no es soportado en IE 8 y versiones anteriores :)</p>
```

Comment: el boton está dentro de un template

Comment: <template id="crud-template">
 <tr>
  <td class="nombre"></td>
  <td class="constelacion"></td>
  <td>
   <button class="editar" style="color:green">Editar</button>
   <button class="eliminar" style="color:red">Eliminar</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</template>

Comment: el evento solo funciona si presiono en los bordes del boton, pero si hago click en el medio...no hace nada la aplicacion